# Word elements relating to ancient deities

Tags: morphology, etymology, historical-linguistics

Are there word elements, including suffixes, from Old English or other languages that have been linked to their ancient deities and the people that served them, to which these elements are still in use today in the evolution of their language?    e.g.:

Jehovah/Jesus Christ a.k.a. Cristos; Christus derived to: Christian; Christianity; Christen; Christendom; Christening; Christhood; Christmas; Christadelphinian & Anti-Christ to name a few. The suffix 'ist' has been applied to many modern English words over the centuries. Have other deities produced this kind of impact upon society?

I hope this clarifies better what I am asking for the sake of the academic community.

Comment: Could you give some examples?

Comment: Is [this the sort of thing](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/dei.pdf) you're talking about?

Comment: Do you mean full words to? Does *venereal* qualify as deriving from Venus, or *martial* deriving from Mars? - - - I was not quite able to parse this 3 lines question.

Comment: @jlawler- I guess I should have said, "in addition to the days of the week", and yes that is the sort of thing I am looking for only leaning more to elements instead of whole words.

Comment: @fdb- One possible example comes to mind, namely, 'ng' is a letter of the Runic alphabet and cognates with the deity 'Ingwas' to which his followers were known as the 'Ing' thus evolving into a suffix commonly used today in many words.

Comment: @babou- My previous comment explains what I am looking for best but your examples are useful. I welcome more input.

Comment: The Runic letter ng, the name Ingwas, and the suffix -ing have absolutely nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @fdb- Why? Do you have a better theory?

Comment: You can look up the etymology of -ing in any good dictionary.

Comment: @fdb- There are many good dictionaries around, some are more comprehensive than others. What would you suggest? I was under the opinion that scholars were open books on this subject so I was anxious to read it straight from your mind as I have from other scholars.

Comment: The -ist- in Greek Christos (English Christ) is part of the word. It has no connection with the suffix -istes (English -ist).

Comment: @fdb- How did this suffix 'ist' get started then?

Comment: @fdb- Not to deviate too far from my original question but it came to me that the name 'Christ', anointed, could have been derived from the Greek word 'Eucharistia' meaning a giving of thanks or oblation to God. Has the word element 'ist' evolved into a common suffix? I ponder now to understand the motivation behind using 'ist' in the creation of so many words to expand the English language. Perhaps you could comment on that further providing me with evidence to prove or disprove this hypothetical question leading to the truth that all of us surely want.

Comment: Actually the suffix "ist" is very successful because it was the first
word of the English language, at the very beginning when such words were
created. At the time, its was actually written "1st", but spelling
evolution simplified the writing into the now common "ist", possibly
because it was felt illogical that the first would turn into a suffix.
The relation with early religion is quite obvious as the three letters
stand for Iupiter, Saturn and the Titans.

Comment: @babou- I followed up on what you said going to the Q&A Wiki with that same question, namely, What was the first word in the English Language? To which their response was, "Their is no answer to this question. Languages evolve over time..." I went then to A Concise Anglo-Saxon Dictionary by John Clark Hall of 1916 and there wasn't a listing for 'ist' in Old English. Webster's Intern. Dict. of 1947 lists the word having come from Latin & Greek. From this evidence it appears that the word came into use in English after the 12th century unless you can produce other evidence as I asked for.

Comment: @fdb- Why is my question still on hold and why did my score go from -1 to 0 and back to -1 again? Not that I am really keeping score but I am wondering about the motive behind the voter.

Comment: It is apparent to me that communication has ceased concerning my question and so I will answer it myself here being unable to do it in the customary way. Since no one could produce evidence under the format I outlined, the truth of the following verse speaks for itself: "...there is none other name given under heaven save it be this Jesus Christ, of which I have spoken, whereby man can be saved." 2 Nephi 25:20 compare to Acts 4:12. No offense is intended to anyone but I make no apologies either for my testimony given here. by Duane T. Bentz duane.bentz@usu.edu

Answer (score 3):

I assumed the question implied words other than the days of the week,
interesting because different but "functionally" related deities have
named them such as Frigg in English for Friday, and Venus in French
for vendredi.

I  guess it also excluded the names of planets and other bodies of the
solar system, which are direct reuses. However some of them produced
derived word. For example **martian**, originally intended to denote the
inhabitants of planet Mars, has become common enough to be sometimes
used to just mean extra-terrestrial being.

You have many words, often adjectives, with a meaning related to
characteristics or attributes of the gods, for example:

**venereal**: having to do with physical love, mostly used in medical context.

**aphrodisiac**: substance that increases sexual desire, from the
  Greek goddes Aphrodite

**martial**: related to fight and army, from Mars, Roman god of war.

**jovial**: from the Roman god Iupiter (genitive Iovis)

**bacchanal**:  a crazed party with drunken revelry

**cereal**: and all derived words, from Ceres, Roman goddess of agriculture.

**volcano**: and all derived words, from Vulcan, the name of a god of fire in Roman mythology.

**vulcanize**: and all derived words, from Vulcan, the name of a god
of fire in Roman mythology

**hermetic**: from Hermes, via the vocabulary of alchemy.

The names of many chemical element s derive from names of ancient
gods:

**Cerium**: named after the asteroid Ceres, named itself after the Roman
goddess;
**Copernicium** named after Copernicus, western god of astronomy;
**Helium**: named after the greek  Helios, the sun or sun-god;
**Iridium**: named after the greek Iris, goddess of rainbows;
**Mercury**: named after the Roman god Mercury;
**Neptunium**: named after the planet Neptune, named itself after the Roman god;
**Palladium**: named after the asteroid Ceres,named itself after the Greek
goddess Pallas Athena;
**Plutonium**: Named after Pluto, named itself after the Roman god Pluto;
**Uranium**: after the planet Uranus, itself named for the greek god Ouranos;
**Vanadium**: from Vanadís, one of the names of the Vanr goddess Freyja in
Norse mythology;

and a few others to be found in the [list of chemical element name etymologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_element_name_etymologies)

And to end this list, which is certainly far from complete, one word
referring to two gods, one male and one female: **Hermaphrodite**.

Answer (score 1):

**Days of week** may be a good example of what you are looking for.
In many IE languages, names of those are derived from ancient deities representing individual planets.

> *In most Indian languages, the word for **Sunday** is Ravivāra or Adityavāra or its derived forms — vāra meaning day, Aditya and Ravi both being a style (manner of address) for Surya, the chief solar **deity** and one of the Adityas.* — [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunday#Etymology)
>
> *In many Languages of India, the word for **Monday** is derived from Sanskrit Somavāra. Soma is another name of the Moon **god** in Hinduism.* — [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monday#Etymology)

Comment: I do not know what this is supposed to prove. The seven-day week originated in the Near East and the Mediterranean world. It was introduced into India by the Muslims. It has no relevance for Indo-European reconstructions.